# Pyspark wrong count when running in yarn

Tags: python, pyspark

I am executing a jupyter notebook with the following sparkContext settings:

### Session

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master("yarn") \
.config("spark.executor.memory", "1g") \
.config("spark.executor.cores", "1") \
.config("spark.executor.instances", "1") \
.config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.yarn.queue","datascience.jupyter") \
.appName('jupyter-session') \
.getOrCreate()
```

Then I load a couple of parquet files:

```py
document = spark.read.parquet('/agg/document.parquet')
archive = spark.read.parquet('/agg/archive.parquet')
```

The context of the problem, is looking at a series of events over time. And the ultimate result of the computation in the dataframe, is obtaining a flag when all events are not in state 0 or 5.

The solution, uses a dictionary, to maintain the state of the group, and implemented as a `udf` in pyspark. The code is as follows:

### UDF

```py
@F.udf(T.ArrayType(T.LongType()))
def state(m):
    d = {}
    for k,v in m.items():
        d[k] = v
    return list(d.values())
```

### Test Data

```
test_workflow = [
    (1,1,10,0),
    (1,2,10,0),
    (1,3,10,0),
    (1,4,10,0),
    (1,1,11,8),
    (1,2,12,8),
    (1,3,12,8),
    (1,3,13,1),
    (1,4,14,8)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(test_workflow, ('WorkflowId', 'DocumentId', 'DistanceFromCreation', 'Status'))
```

Finally I run a series of transformations over the `document` dataframe.

### Computation

```py
%%time

U = df\
.withColumn('DocumentSet', F.collect_list(F.col('DocumentId')).over(Window.partitionBy('WorkflowId').orderBy('DistanceFromCreation').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)))\
.withColumn('StatusSet', F.collect_list(F.col('Status')).over(Window.partitionBy('WorkflowId').orderBy('DistanceFromCreation').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)))\
.withColumn('Mapper', F.map_from_arrays(F.col('DocumentSet'), F.col('StatusSet')))\
.withColumn('Completion', state(F.col('Mapper')))

U.show(truncate=False)
```

### Output

The outcome looks like this:

```
+----------+----------+--------------------+------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|WorkflowId|DocumentId|DistanceFromCreation|Status|DocumentSet                |StatusSet                  |Mapper                                                                  |Completion  |
+----------+----------+--------------------+------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|1         |1         |10                  |0     |[1]                        |[0]                        |[1 -> 0]                                                                |[0]         |
|1         |2         |10                  |0     |[1, 2]                     |[0, 0]                     |[1 -> 0, 2 -> 0]                                                        |[0, 0]      |
|1         |3         |10                  |0     |[1, 2, 3]                  |[0, 0, 0]                  |[1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0]                                                |[0, 0, 0]   |
|1         |4         |10                  |0     |[1, 2, 3, 4]               |[0, 0, 0, 0]               |[1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0]                                        |[0, 0, 0, 0]|
|1         |1         |11                  |8     |[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]            |[0, 0, 0, 0, 8]            |[1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 1 -> 8]                                |[8, 0, 0, 0]|
|1         |2         |12                  |8     |[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]         |[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8]         |[1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 1 -> 8, 2 -> 8]                        |[8, 8, 0, 0]|
|1         |3         |12                  |8     |[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]      |[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8]      |[1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 1 -> 8, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 8]                |[8, 8, 8, 0]|
|1         |3         |13                  |1     |[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3]   |[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 1]   |[1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 1 -> 8, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 8, 3 -> 1]        |[8, 8, 1, 0]|
|1         |4         |14                  |8     |[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]|[0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 1, 8]|[1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 1 -> 8, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 8, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 8]|[8, 8, 1, 8]|
+----------+----------+--------------------+------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+

CPU times: user 33.4 ms, sys: 7.14 ms, total: 40.5 ms
Wall time: 14.8 s
```

### Transformation

```py
df\
    .withColumn('DocumentSet', F.collect_list(F.col('DocumentId')).over(Window.partitionBy('WorkflowId').orderBy('DistanceFromCreation').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)))\
    .withColumn('StatusSet', F.collect_list(F.col('Status')).over(Window.partitionBy('WorkflowId').orderBy('DistanceFromCreation').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)))\
    .withColumn('Mapper', F.map_from_arrays(F.col('DocumentSet'), F.col('StatusSet')))\
    .withColumn('Total', state(F.col('Mapper')))\
    .withColumn('Complete', ~(F.array_contains(F.col('Total'),0) | F.array_contains(F.col('Total'),5)))\
    .withColumn('Derivative', F.col('Complete').cast('integer'))\
    .withColumn('Lag', F.lag(F.col('Derivative')).over(Window.partitionBy('WorkflowId').orderBy('DistanceFromCreation')))\
    .withColumn("CleanLag", F.when(F.isnull(F.col('Lag')), 0).otherwise(F.col('Lag')))\
    .withColumn("Marker", F.col('Derivative') - F.col('CleanLag'))\
    .where(F.col('Marker') == 1)\
    .count()
```

### Result

The output of the computation differs, when I change the configuration of the session to:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master("yarn") \
.config("spark.executor.memory", "1g") \
.config("spark.executor.cores", "3") \
.config("spark.executor.instances", "3") \
.config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.yarn.queue","datascience.jupyter") \
.appName('jupyter-session') \
.getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the use of the `collect_set` and `collect_list` functions. Together with the `map_from_arrays` functions. The functions are non deterministic after shuffle, and I had collisions in the entries inside the windows.
The iterative build of the map entries was producing different results, and therefore wrong counts every time.

### Solution:

1. Use an additional sort criteria inside the windows to avoid collisions and bring determinism to the computation
2. Migrate to spark `3.0.0` and using the `LAST_WIN` configuration setting, to avoid using a custom `udf` handlding the construction of the map, as per the note below

> **From spark documentation**
> In Spark version 2.4 and below, you can create a map with duplicated keys via built-in functions like CreateMap, StringToMap, etc. The behavior of map with duplicated keys is undefined, for example, map look up respects the duplicated key appears first, Dataset.collect only keeps the duplicated key appears last, MapKeys returns duplicated keys, etc. In Spark 3.0, Spark throws RuntimeException when duplicated keys are found. You can set spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy to LAST_WIN to deduplicate map keys with last wins policy. Users may still read map values with duplicated keys from data sources which do not enforce it (for example, Parquet), the behavior is undefined

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.